# Converting char hex string to unsigned int using strtoul function in C

Tags: c, strtoull

I am tring to convert hex to unsigned int from `strtoul` function. But I am getting output as `ffffffff`.
I have used `stdlib.h` library.
Can someone tell me at what part I am wrong?

```
void main()
{
   char str1[33] = "88CC6069E4EDF969773369F988CC969F";
   unsigned int hex_int;
   hex_int = strtoul(str1, NULL, 16); //converting to unsigned int
   printf("%x\n", hex_int);
}
```

Comment: On most platforms today `int` is a 32-bit type, and the value in your string is *way* bigger than 32 bits (way bigger than the 64 bits of `long long` even).

Comment: Also `[32]` --> `[33]` or `[]`

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Complement to BLUXPIXY's coomment: `char str1[32] = "88CC6069E4EDF969773369F988CC969F";`: your `str1` array won't be `NUL` terminated, so any `str...` function upon `str1` would fail anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "On most platforms today int is a 32-bit type" - Most platforms today are still 8 or 16 bits with 16 bit `int`. This is true for total units sold as well as the number of architectures.

Comment: @Olaf Ok, on most *PC-type* platforms `int` is 32 bits...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not that 16 bit `int` would change the problem ;-)

Comment: The first chapter of a beginner C programming book usually addresses the maximum limits of integer types.

Answer (score 1):

C11 [7.22.1.4p8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4p8):

> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. *If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), **and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.***

Try the following code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "88CC6069E4EDF969773369F988CC969F";
    errno = 0; // must reset errno first, otherwise it can retain an old value
    unsigned long int hex_int = strtoul(str1, NULL, 16); 
    if (errno != 0) {
        perror("strtoul failed:");
    }
}
```

On my machine it will output

> ```
>  strtoul failed: Numerical result out of range
> ```

You make 2 mistakes: the value returned by `strtoul` is an `unsigned`**`long`**; and even then, your value is 128 bits which is larger than the `unsigned long` on any common platform.

---

And also, do not bound the length of `str1` - it should be at least 33 characters; or use a pointer-to-char instead:

```
char *str1 = "88CC6069E4EDF969773369F988CC969F";
```

---

And, `int main(void)`.

Comment: Don't forget to reset `errno` before calling `strtoul()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another manual version :

```
#include <ctype.h> // To use isdigit(), this function is not necessary if you can use ASCII table

const int asciiNumberBetweenDigitAndAlpha = 7; // see ASCII table
int str2[32];
const int size = sizeof(str1);

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    if (isdigit(readLine[i]))
        str2[i] = str1[i] - '0'; // In ASCII '0' = 48; '1' = 49..
    else
        str2[i] = str1[i] - '0' - asciiNumberBetweenDigitAndAlpha;
}
```

You could use, as an alternative to the ugly `else`part :

```
if (str1[i] == 'A')
   str2[i] = 10;
else if (str1[i] == 'B')
   str2[i] = 11;
...
```

Answer (score -1):

use `strtoull` for larger numbers.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/strtoull.htm